# If $\sup A < \sup B$, does $B$ contain an upper bound of $A$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

If A and B are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$  and $\sup A < \sup B$, does $B$ contain an upper bound of $A$?

---

So, the trivial case is if supB is contained in B. The Archimedean property would be my first guess for the supB not contained in B part. But how would you construct an argument for that?

Comment: So, the trivial case is if supB is contained in B. The Archimedean property would be my first guess for the supB not contained in B part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Let $\epsilon = \frac{\sup(B)-\sup(A)}{2}$.

By the definition of $\sup(B)$ there exists an element $b \in B$ such that $b \geq \sup(B) -\epsilon$....